# 'Hardly any of us consider' or 'Hardly any of us considers'?

Tags: grammar

Any is supposed to be singular but the latter sounded kinda unidiomatic

Comment: The singular version sounds pretty idiomatic to me.

Comment: @sumelic has '_Any of_ can be followed by a verb in the singular or plural: "If any of your friends want/wants to come, they are welcome." (Plural is preferred in everyday language, singular is more formal)', apparently from 'GrammarBlog' (and backed up by some stats). 'Hardly any of ...' is likely to follow the same pattern.